# How to use variables in list comprehensions?

Tags: coffeescript

I have following Coffeescript code:

```
result = ([number, process = number * 2, process] for number in [1, 2, 3])
```

Which compiles into:

```
var number, process, result;

result = (function() {
  var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
  _ref = [1, 2, 3];
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    number = _ref[_i];
    _results.push([number, process = number * 2, process]);
  }
  return _results;
})();
```

The result is a multidimensional array:

```
[ [1, 2, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 6, 6] ]
```

Let´s assume that `process` is calculated very costly and I want to use that value as argument for several different functions:

```
result = ([number, process = /* costly calculation */, function1(process), function2(process), function3(process)] for number in [1, 2, 3])
```

This works actually fine. However, I do not want the value of `process` itself to be an element of the resulting array. Its value is now still the second element of the array. When I look at the compiled Javascript I can easily move the definition of `process` out of the array like that:

```
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    number = _ref[_i];
    process = number * 2;
    _results.push([number, process]);
}
```

**How can I do that in Coffeescript?**

Try it [online](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aresult%20=%20%28%5Bnumber,%20process%20=%20number%20%2a%202,%20process%5D%20for%20number%20in%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%20result)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this one and this should solve your problem:

```
result = ([number = (process = /* costly calculation */) - process + number, function1(process), function2(process), function3(process)] for number in [1, 2, 3])
```

Here, two extra operations (addition and subtraction) will be done for every number in the array. But, it should not add too much to calculation costs.

It can be optimized further to bring down the calculation cost.

Update:

Use this one when you don't need variables `number`, `process`:

```
result = ([function1(process = /* costly calculation */), function2(process), function3(process)] for number in [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this looks kind of messy. What if I do not even want `number` in my array?

Answer (score 1):

In CoffeeScript blocks are expressions too, so you can do:

```
result = (process = costlyCalculation(); [number, function1(process), function2(process), function3(process)] for number in [1, 2, 3])
```

Or, instead of using semicolons to separate statements, i'd recommend using newlines:

```
result = for number in [1, 2, 3]
  process = costlyCalculation()
  [number, function1(process), function2(process), function3(process)]
```